# Pickup item and changes the icon of the slots inventory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i wanna try to make simpe 6 slots inventory system with this script :

```
Inventory inventory;
    PickUp itemIDs;
    public Sprite[] item;
    public int a;

    void Start()
    {
        inventory = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Inventory>();
        itemIDs = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item").GetComponent<PickUp>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
      a = itemIDs.itemID;

      for(int f = 0; f < inventory.slots.Length; f++)
      {
         if(inventory.isFull[f] == true)
         {
           inventory.slots[f].enabled = true;
           inventory.slots[f].sprite = item[a];
         }
      }
    }
```

and

```
private Inventory inventory;
    private Slots slots;
    public int itemID = 1;
    public GameObject item;
    

    void Start()
    {
        inventory = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Inventory>();
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots").GetComponent<Slots>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
    
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
           for(int f = 0; f < inventory.slots.Length; f++)
           {
             if(inventory.isFull[f] == false)
              {
              inventory.slots[f].enabled = true;
              inventory.isFull[f] = true;
              Instantiate(item, inventory.slots[f].transform, false);
              Destroy(gameObject);
              break;
              }
           }
            
        }
        
    }
```

but the sprite of the inventory.slots.sprite keeps turning 0, when i use inventory.slots[f].sprite = item[a];

and a = itemIDs.itemID; but the a keeps turning to 0, PLLSSS HELPPS

Comment: your first chunk of code assigns to a slot only if its full

Comment: the slots.sprite.enabled is off/false when the isFull is not full (inventory empty) , am i wrong??

Comment: tbh wiith the code snippets provided who knows, however, the first chunk of code, tests if isfull==true and then puts something in it... so Id say thats why it always fills 0..